# Splitting a path using containing \ and / using a RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I want to split a path containing  **forward**  and/or **backward** slashes into parts using Google Apps script.
I prefer doing this by using a single RegExp instead of writing much code.

so code should look like

```
var myPath  = "<something>";        // i.e.   \first\second/third\filename.extension
var parts = myPath.replace(<a regular expression>).split('/');
```

Allthough I searched SO, I didn't find a solution.

What should `<a regular expression>` be?

Comment: `'/\/\\/'`. looks like leaning toothpicks, so you may want a different delimieter, e.g. `'|/\\|'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just going to split, there's no need to replace beforehand then split. You can pass the regex to the `split` function directly. Like this:

```js
var parts = mPath.split(/[/\\]/);
```

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. For someone who is familiar with regex it should be an easy thing to do, but I never paid attention to regex (unfortunally). Thanks !

Comment: It's never too late to learn. Knowing regex is very helpful in many situations.

Comment: Please post a new question. The goal here on StackOverflow is to create Q&A entries that can be useful to many. Comments discussion are hardly helpful. Specially if not tightly related. When posting your question, remember to also tag `javascript`, since this is pretty generic and not really Apps Script specific.